# Why is Convert being used in this statement and how does it differ from CAST?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

This is a piece of code on MSDN page for OVER clause:

```
USE AdventureWorks2012;
GO
SELECT BusinessEntityID, TerritoryID      
,DATEPART(yy,ModifiedDate) AS SalesYear
,CONVERT(varchar(20),SalesYTD,1) AS  SalesYTD
,CONVERT(varchar(20),AVG(SalesYTD) OVER (PARTITION BY TerritoryID 
                                        ORDER BY DATEPART(yy,ModifiedDate) 
                                       ),1) AS MovingAvg
,CONVERT(varchar(20),SUM(SalesYTD) OVER (PARTITION BY TerritoryID 
                                        ORDER BY DATEPART(yy,ModifiedDate) 
                                        ),1) AS CumulativeTotal
FROM Sales.SalesPerson
WHERE TerritoryID IS NULL OR TerritoryID < 5
ORDER BY TerritoryID,SalesYear;
```

So I am having issues understanding why CONVERT function had to be used there. I assume it is to do with return types of one of the fields in the expression part of the convert function? Can CAST be used instead? 
Second question I have is, how exactly does this part work?

```
SUM(SalesYTD) OVER (PARTITION BY TerritoryID
ORDER BY DATEPART(yy,ModifiedDate)
```

What exactly is that saying? Is it calculating sum for every year? Is that it?

Comment: `CONVERT` has a bit more functionality than` CAST`, so why not use it even for simpler cases?  And the `OVER (PARTITION BY` is generating a row set that fills out the required `AVG` and `SUM`.  Looking at the example data shown just below the code should help you see what is happening.   Your code is found at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx

Comment: By the way, you can download AdventureWorks and run this query to see result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Convert style

- If SalesYTD type is float or real:

  1 = Always 8 digits. Always use in scientific notation.
- If type is money and small money:

  1 = Commas every three digits to the left of the decimal point, and two digits to the right of the decimal point; for example, 3,510.92.

> Cast will use the default value for style: 0

- If SalesYTD type is float or real:

  0 (default) = A maximum of 6 digits. Use in scientific notation, when appropriate.
- If type is money and small money:

  0 (default) = No commas every three digits to the left of the decimal point, and two digits to the right of the decimal point; for example, 4235.98.

There are other differences and default values for style with other types but I think it covers your data types. See [CAST and CONVERT (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928(v=sql.120).aspx)

> SUM window function

For each partition (=TerritoryID) it takes all SalesYTD, order them by DATEPART(yy,ModifiedDate) and sum them. Note that the Order part is not necessary or could be anything since you only do SUM and AVG but using it change the behaviors (see hypercube answer about it and moving average). With ROW_NUMBER and others, it would be important and mandatory.

Diffence between SUM and moving SUM (@hypercube answer):

```
declare @data table(TerritoryID int, SalesYTD int, ModifiedDate date)
insert into @data(TerritoryID, SalesYTD, ModifiedDate) values
(1, 1, '20100101')
, (1, 2, '20110101')
, (1, 3, '20120101')
, (1, 4, '20130101')
, (1, 5, '20140101')
, (2, 6, '20150101')
, (2, 7, '20160101')
, (2, 8, '20170101')

Select *
    , [Moving SUM] = SUM(SalesYTD) OVER (PARTITION BY TerritoryID ORDER BY DATEPART(yy,ModifiedDate))
    , [SUM] = SUM(SalesYTD) OVER (PARTITION BY TerritoryID)
From @data
```

Output:

```
TerritoryID | SalesYTD | ModifiedDate | Moving SUM    | SUM
---------------------------------------------------------------------
1           | 1        | 2010-01-01   | 1 => 1        | 10 => 1+2+3+4
1           | 2        | 2011-01-01   | 3 => 1+2      | 10 => 1+2+3+4
1           | 3        | 2012-01-01   | 6 => 1+2+3    | 10 => 1+2+3+4
1           | 4        | 2013-01-01   | 10 => 1+2+3+4 | 10 => 1+2+3+4
2           | 6        | 2015-01-01   | 6 => 6        | 21 => 6+7+8
2           | 7        | 2016-01-01   | 13 => 6+7     | 21 => 6+7+8
2           | 8        | 2017-01-01   | 21 => 6+7+8   | 21 => 6+7+8
```

See [OVER Clause (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461(v=sql.120).aspx) for window functions.

Answer (score 5):

Regarding the window aggregates (`SUM()` and `AVG()` with `OVER (...)`:

```
SUM(SalesYTD) OVER (PARTITION BY TerritoryID
                    ORDER BY DATEPART(yy,ModifiedDate))
```

The MSDN page [`OVER` Clause (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx) has this (rather hidden) remark:

> **General remarks**
>   ...
>   If `ORDER BY` is not specified entire partition is used for a window frame. This applies only to functions that do not require `ORDER BY` clause. **If `ROWS/RANGE` is not specified but `ORDER BY` is specified, `RANGE UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW` is used as default for window frame.** This applies only to functions that have can accept optional `ROWS/RANGE` specification. For example, ranking functions cannot accept `ROWS/RANGE`, therefore this window frame is not applied even though `ORDER BY` is present and `ROWS/RANGE` is not.

which means that your code above has the same results as:

```
SUM(SalesYTD) OVER (PARTITION BY TerritoryID
                    ORDER BY DATEPART(yy, ModifiedDate)
                    RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING 
                              AND CURRENT ROW)
```

so the `SUM()` is calculated (for a row) by getting all rows that have the same `TerritoryID` and the year part of the `ModifiedDate` is less or equal the year part of the row. This is often called a "*cumulative total*" as it has the total of all values from the starting value (minimum year in the example) up to (all the rows) of the current value (year). The same applies to the `AVG()` calculation (which is often called "*moving average*".

Answer (score 2):

In AdventureWorks database column SalesYTD is `MONEY` type, so in this case use `CONVERT` with style=1 means:

> Commas every three digits to the left of the decimal point, and two
>   digits to the right of the decimal point; for example, 3,510.92.

[CAST and CONVERT (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)

And some words about `AVG()` and `SUM()` using with `OVER(PARITION BY ... ORDER BY ...)` statement.

Here is result from AdvetureWorks:

```
BusinessEntityID TerritoryID SalesYear   SalesYTD             MovingAvg            CumulativeTotal
---------------- ----------- ----------- -------------------- -------------------- --------------------
274              NULL        2001        677,558.47           677,558.47           677,558.47
287              NULL        2002        636,440.25           656,999.36           1,313,998.72
285              NULL        2003        219,088.88           511,029.20           1,533,087.60
283              1           2001        3,587,378.43         1,793,689.21         3,587,378.43
280              1           2001        0.00                 1,793,689.21         3,587,378.43
284              1           2002        1,931,620.18         1,839,666.20         5,518,998.61
275              2           2001        4,557,045.05         4,557,045.05         4,557,045.05
277              3           2001        3,857,163.63         3,857,163.63         3,857,163.63
276              4           2001        5,200,475.23         4,109,600.36         8,219,200.72
281              4           2001        3,018,725.49         4,109,600.36         8,219,200.72
```

**MovingAvg** means average SalesYTD since begining (into current partition) to this row  in order by year of SalesYear ascending.

**CumulativeTotal** means sum SalesYTD since begining (into current partition) to this row in order by year of SalesYear ascending.